# How to use Sherman Serif font in ggplot2 for all parts of a plot (e.g., title, x.axis, y.axis)

Tags: r, ggplot2, extrafont

How can I force ggplot2 to use Sherman Serif font by default in all parts of a plot including title, y.axis, x.axis, etc? Preferably, I would like to do this once at the beginning of my syntax.

Thanks,

Nader

Comment: If the font is already installed to your OS and imported to your environment, you just need to do `theme_set(theme_xx(base_family="Sherman Serif"))` (please use the exact font name after `base_family=`).

Comment: Thanks! How can I make sure my font of interest has been installed and imported to my environment?

Comment: Also, I got an error:  could not find function "theme_xx"

Comment: 1) I'm sorry I don't fully understand font issues in R, but it seems that `extrafont::fonts()` lists up all the existing font names so please check if it's there. 2) Please use the theme you prefer: `theme_gray`, `theme_bw`, etc.